# Posting AJAX to SObject Tree resource not working

Tags: post

been trying to have custom field in my opportunity . when the post happens I get the object in the right format however it doesnt post it, and doesnt really tell me the issue 
here is the object

```
accountInfoJson {"records":[{"attributes":{"type":"Account","referenceId":"acc1"},"name":"everything","billingstreet":"asdfasf\nundefined","billingcity":"TORRANCE","billingstate":"CA","billingpostalcode":"90275","Contacts":{"records":[{"attributes":{"type":"Contact","referenceId":"con1"},"firstname":"rerer","lastname":"rerer","Phone":"454654","Email":"23sdf@gmail.com"}]},"Opportunities":{"records":[{"attributes":{"type":"Opportunity","referenceId":"opp1"},"name":"everything","closedate":"2018-09-01","stagename":"Prospecting","Number_of_Seat_Trunks__c":"12","Voice_MRC__c":"20.00","Bandwidth_MRC__c":"20.00","Hardware_MRC__c":"20.00","CM_s_Quota_Value__c":"20.00"}]}}]}
```

the fields that are custom are all currency

here is my POST

```
var accountInfo = { "records": [{
   "attributes": { "type": "Account", "referenceId": "acc1" },
   "name": $( "input[id*='name']" ).val(),

"billingstreet": $( "input[id*='pqStreet']" ).val()+'\n'+ 
                 $("select[id*='unValue']").val(),
"billingcity": $( "input[id*='pqCity']" ).val(),
"billingstate": $( "[id*='pqState'] option:selected" ).val(), 
"billingpostalcode": $( "input[id*='pqZip']" ).val(),

   "Contacts": {
     "records": [{
       "attributes": { "type": "Contact", "referenceId": "con1" },
       "firstname": $('[id*="contactFirstName"]').val(),
       "lastname": $('[id*="contactLastName"]').val(),
       "Phone": $('[id*="contactPhone"]').val(),
       "Email": $('[id*="contactEmail"]').val()
     }]
   },
   "Opportunities": {
     "records": [{
       "attributes": { "type": "Opportunity", "referenceId": "opp1" },

        "name": $('[id="oppName"]').val(),
       "closedate": $('[id*="closedate"]').val(),
       "stagename": "Prospecting",
       "Number_of_Seat_Trunks__c": $('[id*="Number_of_Seat_Trunks__c"]').val(),
       "Voice_MRC__c": $('[id*="Voice_MRC__c"]').val(),
       "Bandwidth_MRC__c": $('[id*="Bandwidth_MRC__c"]').val(),
       "Hardware_MRC__c": $('[id*="Hardware_MRC__c"]').val(),
       "CM_s_Quota_Value__c": $('[id*="CM_s_Quota_Value__c"]').val()
     }]
   }
 }]
};
console.log('accountInfoJson ', accountInfo );

var accountInfoJson = JSON.stringify(accountInfo);
console.log('accountInfoJson ' + accountInfoJson );
$.ajax({    type: "POST",
    url: "/services/data/v42.0/composite/tree/Account",
    headers : {
        'Authorization' : "Bearer " + "{!$Api.Session_Id}" ,
         'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                  },
       data : accountInfoJson,
       success : function(response){

                    console.log('response fasf sa fsf',response);
                            },
       error: function(response){
       console.log(response);
                    displayError(response);

                            }
                        });


            })
```

all I see in console is 
{readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}

Uncaught ReferenceError: displayError is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're putting numbers inside of quotes. You need to use parseFloat to get the correct values:

```
"CM_s_Quota_Value__c": parseFloat($('[id*="CM_s_Quota_Value__c"]').val())
```

Numbers must not be quoted in JSON in order to be valid. Your actual JSON should look like:

```
"CM_s_Quota_Value__c": 20.00,
```

Note that the number is not quoted.